# How to iterate over files in an S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a large number of files (>1,000) stored in an S3 bucket, and I would like to iterate over them (e.g. in a `for` loop) to extract data from them using `boto3`.

However, I notice that in accordance with http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects, the `list_objects()` method of the `Client` class only lists up to 1,000 objects:

```
In [1]: import boto3

In [2]: client = boto3.client('s3')

In [11]: apks = client.list_objects(Bucket='iper-apks')

In [16]: type(apks['Contents'])
Out[16]: list

In [17]: len(apks['Contents'])
Out[17]: 1000
```

However, I would like to list **all** the objects, even if there are more than 1,000. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As kurt-peek notes, `boto3` has a [`Paginator`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#paginators) class, which allows you to iterator over pages of s3 objects, and can easily be used to provide an iterator over items within the pages:

```
import boto3


def iterate_bucket_items(bucket):
    """
    Generator that iterates over all objects in a given s3 bucket

    See http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2 
    for return data format
    :param bucket: name of s3 bucket
    :return: dict of metadata for an object
    """


    client = boto3.client('s3')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)

    for page in page_iterator:
        if page['KeyCount'] > 0:
            for item in page['Contents']:
                yield item


for i in iterate_bucket_items(bucket='my_bucket'):
    print i
```

Which will output something like:

```
{u'ETag': '"a8a9ee11bd4766273ab4b54a0e97c589"',
 u'Key': '2017-06-01-10-17-57-EBDC490AD194E7BF',
 u'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 10, 17, 58, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 u'Size': 242,
 u'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}
{u'ETag': '"03be0b66e34cbc4c037729691cd5efab"',
 u'Key': '2017-06-01-10-28-58-732EB022229AACF7',
 u'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 10, 28, 59, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 u'Size': 238,
 u'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}
...
```

Note that `list_objects_v2` is recommended instead of `list_objects`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

You can also do this at a lower level by calling [`list_objects_v2()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) directly and passing in the `NextContinuationToken` value from the response as `ContinuationToken` while `isTruncated` is true in the response.

Comment: wonderful!! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I found out that `boto3` has a [Paginator](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html) class to deal with truncated results. The following worked for me:

```
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='iper-apks')
```

after which I can use the `page_iterator` generator in a `for` loop.

Comment: The documentation suggests using "list_objects_v2" for new development see -  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html - this is also supported by the paginator, see http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2

Answer (score -1):

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest
import java.util._

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build()
val listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("<enter_bucket_name>").withPrefix("<enter_path>").withDelimiter("/")
val bucketListing = s3client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest).getCommonPrefixes.asScala

println("")

for (file <- bucketListing) {
    println(file)
}

println("")
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66782105/9193372)